# Does Outlook 2016 for Mac support Exchange 2010(v14.0)?

Tags: mac-osx, exchange-2010, outlook

Some Mac users have updated from Outlook 2011 to 2016 and now are having troubles connecting to an on premise Exchange server with their credentials. The error is "Authentication failed. Check your information". Users get prompted twice to "Allow the autodiscover", but allowing it doesn't make Outlook work anyway.

Seems a majority says Outlook 2016 supports Exchange 2010 and up. Which one, the v14.0? There was only one blog that said minimum requirement is 2010 **SP2**. Does anyone know the specific minimum version supported?

Comment: Does this help? - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2955530

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the full Exchange supportability matrix, including all supported clients: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff728623(v=exchg.150).aspx.

It does indeed look like Outlook 2016 for Mac (included in Office 365 for Mac) supports Exchange 2010, but it needs to be Exchange 2010 **SP3**; this means previous Exchange 2010 versions might or might not work, but they are not supported.

As a side note, if your Exchange 2010 is not already at SP3 level, I *strongly* suggest you upgrade it, and also apply the latest available update rollup (currently UR12, but see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/240.exchange-server-and-update-rollup-build-numbers.aspx); running outdated software is almost never a good idea.